# Printing Substrings

Tags: java, string

I'm too print out all substrings of a word, however; I can't get the last output.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class printer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a word");
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        int i;
        int j;
        for (i=1; i<s.length(); i++) {
            for (j=0; j+i<=s.length(); j++) {
                String ss = s.substring(j, j+i);
                System.out.println(ss);
        } }
    }
}
```

Input

```
thunder
```

Output

```
t
h
u
n
d
e
r
th
hu
un
nd
de
er
thu
hun
und
nde
der
thun
hund
unde
nder
thunde
hunder
(missing thunder)
```

Sure I just put a System.out.println(s); at the end, but I want it to just finish with the for loop

Comment: Oh goodness, it was that easy...

Answer (score 8):

Change your outer for loop condition to `i<=s.length`

Answer (score 6):

Change the check in your first `for` loop iterating on `i` to this:-

```
for (i = 1; i <= s.length(); i++) // "i" should be less than or equal to the length of "s"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take value of i=s.length();

Just make outer loop as `for(i=1; i<=s.length(); i++)`

Answer (score 0):

Make ammendemends  from

```
for (i=1; i<s.length(); i++)

to 
for (i=1; i<=s.length(); i++)
```